# Unable to start secondarynamenode, datanode, nodemanager while starting hadoop

Tags: bigdata, hadoop2

```
I am using Hadoop hadoop-2.6.0, while starting hadoop services unable to start secondarynamenode, datanode, nodemanager services.
Getting Java.net.bind exceptions.
```

NodeManager:

```
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [0.0.0.0:8040] java.net.BindException: Address already in use; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.getServer(RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.HadoopYarnProtoRPC.getServer(HadoopYarnProtoRPC.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.YarnRPC.getServer(YarnRPC.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService.createServer(ResourceLocalizationService.java:356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService.serviceStar
```

NameNode:

```
2017-10-10 23:58:07,872 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: HttpServer.start() threw a non Bind IOException
java.net.BindException: Port in use: 0.0.0.0:50090
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.openListeners(HttpServer2.java:891)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.start(HttpServer2.java:827)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.initialize(SecondaryNameNode.java:276)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.<init>(SecondaryNameNode.java:192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.main(SecondaryNameNode.java:671)
```

DataNode:

```
java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [0.0.0.0:50010] java.net.BindException: Address already in use; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
```

On trying netstat -ntpl command the below ports are in already in use

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50010           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50090           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -             
tcp6       0      0 :::8040                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Please someone suggest me how to kill these ports to resolve this issue.

```
:~/hadoopinstall/hadoop-2.6.0$ jps
18255 org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
27492 RunJar
12387 Jps
11951 ResourceManager
11469 NameNode
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After frequent searches/tries i have found the solution to kill the process(port) without pid.

```
*******@127:~$ sudo fuser -k 50010/tcp
[sudo] password for muralee1857: 
50010/tcp:            1514
*******@127:~$ sudo kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:50010)
*******@127:~$ sudo fuser -k 50010/tcp
*******@127:~$ sudo kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:50090)
*******@127:~$ sudo fuser -k 50090/tcp
50090/tcp:            2110
*******@127:~$ sudo kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:50090)
*******@127:~$ sudo fuser -k 50090/tcp
*******@127:~$ sudo fuser -k 8040/tcp
8040/tcp:             2304
*******@127:~$ sudo kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:8040)
*******@127:~$ sudo fuser -k 8040/tcp
```

Now i am able start all hadoop services.

```
/hadoopinstall/hadoop-2.6.0$ jps
6844 NodeManager
7150 Jps
6547 SecondaryNameNode
6202 NameNode
6702 ResourceManager
6358 DataNode
```

Answer (score 1):

the `netstat` command that you have provided also shows the PID of the process which is listening on that port.

For example

```
[root@dn1 ~]# netstat -ntpl | grep 50010
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50010           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1093/java
```

In the above example, 1093 is the PID of the java process which binds the 50010 port.

You can easily check what process is running and if you have the correct permissions, you can kill the process too using the command.

```
kill -9 1093
```

Comment: In my case i am not getting PID on that command.                           
netstat -ntpl | grep 50010
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50010           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -

Comment: Previously i have installed clouderamanager in my ubuntu system. again i have uninstalled it.

Comment: I see that you are able to use sudo. Is it still true that you can not see the pid of the process?

sudo netstat -ntpl | grep 50010